# html dropdown select default value using jquery after reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, razor, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list which got rendered like this from razor view as below

```
<select class="form-control " id="InsuranceType" name="InsuranceType">
<option value="">All Types</option>
<option value="Medical">Medical Insurance</option>
<option value="Auto">Auto Insurance</option>
<option value="Home">Home Insurance</option></select>
```

and im trying to reset the values using reset button and select value as "ALL Types", but instead it's blank.

JQuery

```
function Reset() {
$("#InsuranceType").val("");
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Working fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/fuyexa3q/

Comment: The code you have provided works fine. Perhaps you are not showing the full full html code here. Maybe the select has another option where both value and text is empty-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable way to select the first item, when the value is empty, is:

```
$("#InsuranceType option:selected").prop("selected", false);
$("#InsuranceType option:first").prop("selected", "selected");
```

This handles a few specific browser issues with the empty value attribute.

Comment: Thank you, first one works. In what case I should use the second one?

Comment: Technically, the first bit just "unselects" everything and the second one "selects" the first item. The result of unselecting everything is usually that the first item will be selected - but I have found that the combination of the two gives you the broadest browser coverage.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Reset() {;
    $("#InsuranceType").val("");
}
```

Remove the `;` from above. It should be :

```
function Reset() {
    $("#InsuranceType").val("");
}
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while typing the code here

Answer (score 0):

```
----------

    <select class="form-control " id="InsuranceType" name="InsuranceType">
    <option value="">All Types</option>
    <option value="Medical">Medical Insurance</option>
    <option value="Auto">Auto Insurance</option>
    <option value="Home">Home Insurance</option>
</select>
<button onclick="Reset()">Reset</button>

function Reset(){
  $("#InsuranceType").val("");
}
```

When i click the btn it returns to All Types